# How to know the mac address of inserted changeset?

Tags: authentication, tfs, changeset

There is an employee whom the team leader suspected him to check in changesets from other employees' TFS accounts, to the Azure TFS.

I thought that knowing the mac address of each changeset will give a clue. How to know the mac address of it?

Please advice if there is a better approach to resolve such issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no such kind of info for a changeset.

You could use changeset command to list the detail info of a changeset. Which will return something as  below:

c:\projects>tf changeset 8675309 /noprompt

```
Changeset: 8675309
User: DOMAIN\JohnG
Date: 01/21/2019 21:03:45
Comment:  This check-in fixes issues in several features.  I also refactored some items in buf.c into a new file named bif.c because buf.c was too hard to parse.
Items:
   $/baz/proj/bif.c           Added
   $/baz/proj/buf.c          Modified, Renamed
Work Items:
   34527     The "Access Denied" message is not descriptive enough.
   35628     The UI flickers when I press the '8', 'y', 'Ctrl', and 'End' buttons at the same time.
Check-in Notes:
   Code Reviewer:  ShellM
   Performance Reviewer: ShellM
   Security Reviewer: ShellM
```

This will return the checked in account and checked in time. According to these info, you could ask team leader directly confirm with the account user if he had done the check-in at that time.

But it's not help to directly point out which employee do this.

A possibility the account user used to use his account to login another machine's Visual Studio. Then account info be cached in Visual Studio/Windows.

If so, just need to ask him to **remove**  account info which stored in **Credential Manager** （*Control Panel-All Control Panel Items-Credential Manager-Windows Manager*）

[image]

Comment: I believe there is a better approach.